# How can I link my BTC or ETH address with my Solana address? Is there a way to store account properties in plain text?

Tags: bitcoin, ethereum, data-storage

I want to build out an application where one can query a BTC address and it will link it to their solana address. But how would I store a BTC or ETH address on the Solana blockchain? What would be the best method and how would I retrieve and verify it?

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it myself, but you can verify BTC and ETH signatures on Solana using this:
https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/programs#secp256k1-program

You could create a program that creates PDAs, each seeded by a BTC address (and a SOL address too if your aim is to associate the two). You would use the above program to secure the account creation (i.e. make sure users actually have the BTC address in question).

Each PDA could store all the metadata you want, including the BTC address itself, and the associated Solana address. And of course, you'll want that Solana address to also sign for the creation of a PDA.